# XHR how to prevent validation of non-XML files?

Tags: javascript, csv, xmlhttprequest

I'm loading a CSV file using XHR. Of course the name suggests it must be used to load XML, but you know, there isn't anything else really to load other kinds of files. What happens is it is trying to validate the result it receives, while it's not required. Perhaps it believes it must be XML, or it might have some internal (wrong / arbitrary) knowledge of what CSV should look like - regardless, it raises an error of the following format:

> Error: not well-formed
>   Source File: file:///~~~/docs/quiz.csv
>   Line: 1, Column: 1
>   Source Code:
>   צמתים,ארץ הגידול,שטח הגידול,אופן הגידול,קטיף/ בציר /
>   איסוף,שאריות,תהליכי עיבוד ושימור,אריזה,הפצת מזון,שווק/פרסום

There isn't actually a CSV standard or anything like that, but even so, I believe that Firefox is trying to validate it as if it was XML (regardless the server sends different mime-type etc.) This doesn't affect the functionality, the loading accomplishes successfully, but the error printed to console still bugs me. So, is there any way to cancel that validation?

Comment: Your error message seems to suggest that you're accessing a file off your local file system. This will cause all sorts of grief because the file system doesn't know how to send the right response headers and is treated with different security concerns by the browser. You need to test XHR on a proper webserver

Comment: Have you tried `XMLHttpRequest().overrideMimeType()`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType)

Comment: @wvxvw, check in FireBug which value have `Content-Type` response header for .csv file. In my case .csv loaded without any error messages in FireBug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
XMLHttpRequest().overrideMimeType()
```

to force the browser to treat the data in your way.

[MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType)